# Why are the durations of hadoop mapper tasks always a multiple of 3 seconds?

Tags: hadoop

Looking over my task logs I noticed all of the mapper tasks finish after a multiple of 3 seconds:

[image]

When I look at the logs for some longer running jobs see the same thing:

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: The daemon that runs to check if all mapper is complete, is run once every 3 secs...

Comment: That can't be the case because task `0000001` and `0000002` finish 2 seconds apart

Comment: an individual daemon starts for each mapper. it checks. Sleeps for 3 secs, checks, etc. i cant edit my comment from all to a...

Comment: interesting... is that daemon configurable?

Comment: not sure... I can't find the support for what I am saying which is why I am just adding comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in older versions of Hadoop the `Task.PROGRESS_INTERVAL` is hard coded to 3000 milliseconds