# Why do my map tasks take at least 3 seconds?

Tags: java, performance, hadoop

I previously asked [Why are the durations of hadoop mapper tasks always a multiple of 3 seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29040170/why-are-the-durations-of-hadoop-mapper-tasks-always-a-multiple-of-3-seconds) and by setting the  value of `Task.PROGRESS_INTERVAL` to a small number (>1000) I was able to get fast running tasks to finish in 3 seconds rather than the 6 they were taking. These tasks are literally processing no data and I'd like to get them to finish more quickly if possible.

What are the parameters that are causing the tasks to take 3 seconds

Comment: Instead of worrying about making no-op map tasks faster, can you short-circuit them entirely?

Comment: That would be idea, although i'm not sure how to do that. I'm doing a scan across hbase with a filter, and most of my regions are returning no data.

Comment: Fewer mappers could partially solve the problem. In my not-particularly-expert experience with tuning MR scans over HBase tables, the fact that most regions return no data given your filter suggests that your data _for this job_ is not evenly distributed across regions. If you really wanted to optimize for this use case, then, you'd need to rethink your row key design for better partitioning. (Not trying to boil the ocean here, just offer a thought on what might be an underlying flaw.)

Comment: yeah, you're definitely right in that fewer mappers would be ideal and that the row key design isn't ideal for what i'm doing.  However the table isn't under my control, so I can't make any changes.